# How to change the actionlinks depending on if a post was inserted before? (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET MVC and I'm doing a little bit well.

What I'm trying to do is, displaying posts. A user can press a link and add a post to a wishlist then a record in wishlist table inserted with the postID, UserID, etc,

If a user has added the post before, the link of addition will be "remove from wishlist".

I did everything smoothly, but how can I chick if a user add this item before?

I mean how can I make the code check if that user add this post to a wishlist then link is going to be changed:

a user didn't add this post: Link -> Add to wishlist    (Action: AddToWishList)

a user added this post: Link -> Remove from wishlist    (Action: RemoveFromWishlist)

Thanks for your help and precious time

Comment: so do you mean you want to override the previous post insert for the same user with same wishlist?

Comment: What I mean is, open the page, see the posts, a user can add a post to a wishlist, if a post already exists in the wishlist the link will be "remove from wishlist"

Comment: In your Action, retrieve all the data from whishlist table , and check  if user exist in that table then pass true in viewBag and in your view check if it true, then don't add link else add that link

Comment: Thanks Amit I'm gonna try it and keep you updated